# Running VB.Net code in my program, without creating instances, or parameters. Is it possible?

Tags: vb.net

I am currently trying to make a program where you can type a VB.NET script into a richtextbox (strCode) and then execute it. Like as if I executed it in Visual Studio.

My current code look like this:

```
    Dim objCompilerParameters As New CompilerParameters
    objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll")
    objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll")
    objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll")
    objCompilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = True
    Dim objCompileResults As CompilerResults
    Dim Provider As CodeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("VisualBasic")

    objCompileResults = Provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(objCompilerParameters, strCode)
    ' Get a reference to the assembly.
    '
    Dim objAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = objCompileResults.CompiledAssembly
    ' Create an instance of the DynamicCode class referenced in the source code.
    '
    Dim objTheClass As Object = objAssembly.CreateInstance("Dynam.DynamicCode")

    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Create a parameter to be passed into the ExecuteCode function in class DynamicCode.

    Dim objFunctionParameters(0) As Object
    objFunctionParameters(0) = "Parameter 1"


    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'Creating Result


    Dim objResult As Object = objTheClass.GetType.InvokeMember("ExecuteCode", _
                    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, objTheClass, objFunctionParameters)


    '---------------------
```

This runs fine .. as long as the namespace in my script is "Dynam", and the public class is "TestClass". Also the Public Function has to be named "ExecuteCode". Just like in the script.

Is there a way to create this, without having to hardcode the function and class names? So I can just call the classes, and functions whatever the user wants to call them.

Thanks in advance. I hope it made a little sense. If not, please let me know.

Comment: Not with System.CodeDom.  You'd have to uplift to Roslyn, it lets you parse the code so you can see the type and method names the user used.  Find useful Google hits by querying for "vb.net roslyn scripting".

Comment: @HansPassant I see that some places, they say that Roslyn is not ready to do that yet. I havent really figured it out.  The Roslyn method doesnt actually compile and run the strCode, does it? It simply can give me the method names ect. Is that understood correctly?

Comment: Hmm, no, programmers are not ready for it yet.  There's a learning curve, just don't assume you are going to rattle this off in less than an hour.  If you don't want to study the docs then at least play with the code samples to get the gist.

Comment: @HansPassant 

Thank you for the help Hans! :) Very kind of you. I will look more into it.

Comment: @ErcanCiftci - I would question whether you actually need the ability for your code to run any possible class name with any possible set of methods and or properties. If the goal is to make your application extensible, you can control the scope of the extensiblity. What I've done in the past, with CodeDom, is create a public Interface class in my project. The script in the text box must implement that interface. My application code will only call into the known methods of the Interface class. The script can then do a variety of tasks from a few known "hooks" into my application.